# How can I add a coordinate system to pst-magneticfield?

Tags: pstricks, plot

For an assignment, I'm asked to draw a schematic of the magnetic field due to two circular coils, parallel to the `$x$-$y$` plane and at height `$z = d/2$` and `$z = -d/2$`. I have settled on pst-magneticfield to plot the field lines, however, I would also like to include coordinate axis for clarity. I've taken a look at the official documentation on https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-magneticfield, but I couldn't find an explanation there. Perhaps it's possible to put it into a tikz enviornment or something similar.

Any type of help is highly appreciated. Have a good day everyone.

EDIT: My current code is:

```
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](4,4)(-4,-4)                             
    \psmagneticfield[linecolor={[HTML]{006633}},N=2,R=2,nL=8,L=3](-4,-4)(4,4)
\end{pspicture*}
```

I would like the z-axis to point straight up in the very middle and the x-axis right in between the current carrying pieces. Additionally, as I have just discovered, I need the current to flow in the opposite direction. Is it possible to achieve that?
Thank you.

Comment: create at least a small example without the coordinate system and show the code here. Then we can simply use it and put  the commands into it.

Comment: I have now provided my current code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-magneticfield}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid=false](4.3,4.3)(-4.3,-4.3)                          
\psmagneticfield[linecolor={[HTML{006633}},N=2,R=2,nL=8,L=3,changeNS](-4,-4)(4,4) 
\psaxes[arrows=->](0,0)(-4,-0.5)(4,4)[$x$,0][$z$,90]
\end{pspicture*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that looks amazing. Do you happen to know whether it's also possible to put specific labels on the axis, like in `pgfplots`? In this case, that would mean replacing plus and minus two on the x-axis by `-R` and `R`, and plus/minus 1.5 on the z-axis by plus/minus `d/2`.

Comment: See documentation of `pst-plot`